# Kentico 9 hotfix error

Tags: kentico

I'm in the intitial stages of setting up our new production VM. Kentico 9 has been installed, but when i apply the same hotfix version we have in development i get this. I'm RDV'd into the VM while attempting this.

[image]

Our infrastructure team set the VM up, and did the base install, and said the matched our DEV, QA, and UAT environments, and we're running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Try to apply hotfix manually.

1) download hotfix setup from http://devnet.kentico.com/download/hotfixes

2) check that hotfix_x_y.exe was downloaded correctly (right-click on exe -> Properties -> Digital Signatures -> select signer and click "Details" - "This digital signature is OK")

3) start hotfix_x_y.exe and follow installation wizard (next, next...), in hotfix utility browse to your instance, next, next...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run [hotfix as remote installation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Hotfix+Instructions+-+Kentico+9#HotfixInstructions-Kentico9-Remoteinstallation)?

Answer (score 0):

Are you logged into your VM with RDP when you are doing this or doing it remotely from another machine?  If remotely, then the answer above might help, but overall I would try re-downloading the hotfix and try again as it appears the hotfix package might of been corrupted during the download process.

One possible cause is if your infrastructure team has the traffic throttled or majorly firewalled on that machine.  If so, sometimes it can cause downloads to miss packets and become corrupted.  If it does not work again, try downloading to another system and then move to that one and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Virgil. I edited my question stating that i'm RDP'd into the VM.